# Law of total variance with i.i.d. positive continuous r.v.s.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, variance

So law of total variance states that:
$$Var(Y) = E[ Var(Y | X)] + Var(E[Y|X])$$
Now it's given that $X,Y$ are positive i.i.d. continuous r.v.s.

As $X,Y$ are independent, it means $E[Y|X] = E[Y]$, which is a constant. Let it be $\mu$.

Then, $$Var(E[Y|X]) = Var(E[Y]) = Var(\mu) = 0$$
Thus, $$Var(Y) = E[ Var(Y | X)] + 0 =  E[ Var(Y | X)]$$

Is my reasoning right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes it is......

Comment: Thank you, @KaviRamaMurthy and user_194421

Answer (score 1):

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(Y\right) = \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{Var}\left(Y\mid X\right)\right] +\operatorname{Var}\left(\operatorname{E}\left[Y\mid X\right]\right)$$
If $Y$ is independent of $X$, then
$$\operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{Var}\left(Y\mid X\right)\right]=\operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{Var}\left(Y\right)\right]$$
And
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(\operatorname{E}\left[Y\mid X\right]\right)=\operatorname{Var}\left(\operatorname{E}\left[Y\right]\right)=0$$
Therefore
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(Y\right) = \operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{Var}\left(Y\right)\right]$$
Which makes sense because the expected value of a constant is equivalent to the constant. So yes, as others have already mentioned, your reasoning is indeed correct.